# How do I change the phone number ID on iMessage on iPad?

Tags: messages, ipad

I get messages on my iPad from my wife's iPhone but not mine.
On messages, her number is listed as an ID but I can't change it to mine. How do I change it?

Comment: Check how both devices are logged in at Settings > messages.  It sounds like both are using the same Apple ID.   Also note that is you start changing what Apple ID is logged in where, there are like 7 places n settings where you can log in with different Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to register a phone number as a Receiving/Sending **id** on iMessage, is via an iPhone.

**Meaning**: you can only register an iMessage phone number as an **id** if you have access to that phone number and you activate your iMessage account with it on an iPhone.

If you want your iPad to receive your iMessages (sent to your phone number) you have to:

- Activate iMessage on your iPhone with your phone number and Apple ID (*your carrier might charge you for this process*);
- **[On your iPad]** Go to *Settings -> Messages -> Enable iMessage*.
- Then, on *Send & Receive* make sure the Apple ID is the same as in your iPhone and your Phone Number should be listed.

If you have already activated iMessage on your iPhone, on your iPad under *Send & Receive* you just have to log in with the same Apple ID as in your iPhone.

I also advise you to **set the same id** for Start New Conversations From on all your devices.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Messages -> Send & Receive and you can change what phone numbers and email addresses you receive iMessages from.

The problem is likely that you are signed into your wife's iCloud account somewhere in iOS. Look at the "Apple ID" line in blue at the top of the settings pane I took you to. If that's not it, check Settings -> iCloud.